# perl start and end line number of match

Tags: perl

I have the following perl command: `perl -l -0777 -sne 'print $& if /\Q$start_word\E\s*(\{(?:[^{}]++|(?1))*+\})/s' -- -start_word="${start_head}" < $path`

It extracts some text from a file, but I'm also interestind between which two lines the text is extracted. Before it prints out the text I want it to print something like: `The text is located between lines 3 and 7.`

Sample input (start_head="START"):

```
Hello World
START{
   here are
    {some lines}
}
more text
down here
```

Expected Output:

```
The text is located between lines 2 and 5.
START{
   here are
    {some lines}
}
```

Current output after calling the perl command doesn't include `The text is located between lines 2 and 5.`

Comment: Please add sample input and expected output

Comment: As far as Perl is concerned, there is only one line per file (`-0777`), and there is only one file. You will need to start counting line feeds.

Comment: Maybe if that's too difficult I would at least like to know how many lines are there in the output, I could find the the line for `START` some other way and then add the number of lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
perl -l -0777 -sne 'if (/\Q$start_word\E\s*(\{(?:[^{}]++|(?1))*+\})/s) {($start, $end, $match) = ($-[0], $+[0], $&); print "The text is located between lines ", scalar(() = substr($_, 0, $start) =~ /(\r*\n|\r)/g) + 1 , " and ", scalar( () = substr($_, 0, $end) =~ /(\r*\n|\r)/g) + 1; print $match;}' -- -start_word="${start_head}" < $path
```

I made it slightly more verbose for clarity.

Test input (Linux end of lines (\n)):

```
1. Hello World
2. Hello World
3. Hello World
4. Hello World
START{
   here are
    {some lines}
}
more text
down here
```

Output:

```
The text is located between lines 5 and 8
START{
   here are
    {some lines}
}
```

The same input with Dos/Windows line terminators (\r\n) do produce the same output.

If you are sure your input text file lines types will be either Mac (\r) or Linux/Unix (\n) but never Dos/Windows (\r\n) then it can be simplified like this:

```
perl -l -0777 -sne 'if (/\Q$start_word\E\s*(\{(?:[^{}]++|(?1))*+\})/s) {print "The text is located between lines ", substr($_, 0, $-[0]) =~ tr/[\r\n]// + 1 , " and ", substr($_, 0, $+[0]) =~ tr/[\r\n]+// + 1; print $&;}' -- -start_word="${start_head}" < $path
```

Output (with the same input):

```
The text is located between lines 5 and 8
START{
   here are
    {some lines}
}
```

Comment: The first solution works if the text starts at line 1, otherwise it's off (numbers are too low). The second one doesn't really work for me, thanks for suggestion though.

Comment: Then I'll need your input that doesn't work. Adding the results with my test input files for both solutions to the answer.

Comment: Here is the file: https://justpaste.it/8h90k start_word/start_head are void sum(int a, int b, int* c), bool isEven(int a), void diff() (excluding commas)

Comment: Indeed, my solution was miscounting empty lines. I fixed it in the first version as you seem to be in the Dos/Windows (\r\n) case.